# How to include folder name in Github Repository URL

Tags: git, github, repository, github-pages

[image: File Structure]

`courseraasignment2` is the name of my repository and `module2_solution` is the name of the folder I uploaded. The URL generated by website is:

`..github.io/courseraassignment2/`

whereas I want the URL to be

`...github.io/courseraassignment2/module2_solution/`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You need to provide more info in your question. At the very least a link to your source repo. Also your question is about GitHub Pages, not git or repository. You also need to demonstrate that you've read the GitHub pages documentation and still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: What happens when you put all your web page source files inside a directory named `module2_solution` inside your repository?

Answer (score 0):

`...github.io/courseraassignment2/tree/gh-pages/module2_solution/index.html`
will you achieve, if you add a folder (module2_solution) and create inside at least one file (index.html) and `push` this.
`tree/gh-pages` define, that you show the gh-pages branch‘s current version of the index.html file (just an example...)

As far as I know, you cannot remove `tree/master` from the url as it could also have other branches (e.g. `tree/develop`). Is unfortunately also the case, if you only have one branch (master), `tree/branch` is needed to find the branch of the respective file (because the files can have different content per branch)